# No se estan recibiendo todos los paquetes al hacer ping (Packet Tracer)

Tags: redes

Hace tiempo no veia la materia de CISCO (mas de un año) y se me ocurrio practicar subneteo con el packet tracer. Quise hacer una practica basica, intentando crear dos subredes usando la direccion IP 192.168.16.0/24:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el diseño de red que tengo en packet tracer (solo con 6 computadoras, 1 switch y 1 router):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparentemente, todo esta en su lugar, pero a la hora de hacer un ping desde una computadora de la subred 1 a otra computadora de la subred 2 en el command prompt, me aparece que 1 paquete no fue recibido y que hubo una perdida del 25%:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya todas las computadoras les asigne sus ip´s y mascara. A los switches ya les asigne un IP en el VLAN 1 por Command Line (o CLI), a los routers tambien en cada puerto respectivo les asigne igual. ¿Porque tendria ese 25% de perdida? y como se puede reparar tal cosa?

Comment: Le indicaste a cada ordenador la puerta de enlace?

Comment: Si lo hice Alex, a las 3 computadoras del lado izquierdo les asigne 192.168.16.30 y a las del lado derecho 192.168.16.62 @Alexmaister